# Trying to read cluttered CSV file

Tags: php, csv

I am trying to read [CSV file](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AlBfO6u_WKZban3HQAp0tEo9K7s) using fgetcsv() php function but It doesn't fetch detail as it supposed to be. I found out that the CSV file is cluttered and has multiple irrelevant commas in starting and in-between.  How do I make this CSV cleaner?

I used str_replace() php function to remove triplets of commas but the commas in starting are still giving me a problem. I tried ltrim() also but that didn't work too.

```
<?php
    $file = "grid.csv";
    $s = file_get_contents($file);
    $s = str_replace(",,,", "", $s);
    //$s = ltrim($s,",");
    $f = "grid1.csv";
    $handle = fopen($f, "w");
    fwrite($handle, $s);
?>
```

I expect the output of this code to be a clean csv file. But I get multiple commas in starting now also in the new file.

This is the Main Code where I was trying to read the file using fgetcsv().

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    echo "in submit</br>";
    if($_FILES['csv_info']['name']){
        echo "some file</br>";
        $filename = explode(".", $_FILES['csv_info']['name']);
        if(end($filename) == 'csv'){
            echo "file is csv</br>".$_FILES['csv_info']['tmp_name'];
            $handle = fopen($_FILES['csv_info']['tmp_name'],"r");
            $sid = 0;
            //$query = "select exists(select 1 from tblMarks)";
            //$choice = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            while($data = fgetcsv($handle)){
                if($sid == 0){
                    $sid = $sid + 1;
                    continue;
                }
                //echo $data;
                $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[0]);
                $physics = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[1]);
                $maths = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[2]);
                $chemistry = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[3]);
                $bio = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[4]);
                $sst = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $data[5]);
                echo "</br>inserting sid".$sid." name=".$name." physics=".$physics." maths=".$maths." chemistry=".$chemistry." bio=".$bio." sst=".$sst."</br>";
                //$query = "insert into tblMarks (sid, name, physics, maths, chemistry, bio, sst) values ('$sid', '$name', '$physics', '$maths','$chemistry','$bio','$sst') on duplicate key update name = '$name', physics = '$physics',maths = '$maths', chemistry = '$chemistry', bio = '$bio', sst ='$sst'";
                //mysqli_query($conn, $query);
                $sid = $sid + 1;
            }
            fclose($handle);
        }
        else{
            $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select CSV File Only</lable>';
        }
    }
    else{
        $message = '<label class="text-danger">Please Select File</label>';
    }
}
```

The output was this:

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MKZkD.jpg)

Comment: Please share csv data example and how do you want the result ?

Comment: You're going to hate to hear this, but if the CSV file is cluttered with commas, then you either need a different delimiter *or* you'll have to manually clean up the file.

Comment: Also `,,,` can mean __empty values__ between them.

Comment: Why don't you use [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) ?

Comment: @Adder "I am trying to read CSV file using fgetcsv() php function but It doesn't fetch detail as it supposed to be"

Comment: @u_mulder Then maybe it is just a matter of setting the parameters of fgetcsv correctly? That is the delimiters?

Comment: @RakeshJakhar I have added the link to CSV file.

Comment: Provide a sample here, 10-15 lines will be enough.

Comment: CSV file is correct. Of course if has some empty lines but nothing "cluttered"

Comment: @u_mulder I have edited the question.

Comment: @Mark check the code posted

Answer (score 1):

here is the correct method to read CSV file row by row. There are many rows in the CSV files which have blank values, to remove theme **array_filter** has been used.

```
$temp = array();
if (($h = fopen("grid.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) 
{
  // Convert each line into the local $data variable
  while (($data = fgetcsv($h, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) 
  {     
    $data = array_filter($data);
    if(count($data) > 0){
        $temp[] = $data;
    }
  }
  fclose($h);
}

//Write csv file

$fp = fopen('grid1.csv', 'w');
foreach ($temp as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields);
}
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Do or do not. There is no "try". A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.